# ssl.SSLError: [X509] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3053)

Tags: 16.04, ssl, certificates

I am having trouble using add-apt-repository

I dont have any self signed certificates and using only system CAs.

```
root@server07:~# add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 335, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 92, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 470, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
ssl.SSLError: [X509] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3053)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 122, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 841, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 407, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 364, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 347, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 304, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 88, in get_info_from_lp
    return _get_https_content_py3(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in _get_https_content_py3
    lp_page = urllib.request.urlopen(request, cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 153, in urlopen
    capath=capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 470, in create_default_context
    context.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath, cadata)
ssl.SSLError: [X509] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3053)
```

I have done this already:

(synchronized time)

```
ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org
```

reinstalled ca certs

```
apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

And updated them

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Source problem is described [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/sslerror-x509-pem-lib--ssl-c-2831/25895) and [here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/sslerror-x509-pem-lib--ssl-c-2831-v2/29521)

Anyone any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit:

printenv output:

```
XDG_SESSION_ID=22649
COMP_WORDBREAKS=    
"'><;|&(:
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8
SSH_CLIENT=... 56684 ..
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/2
USER=root
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib:
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
ORACLE_SID=XE
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
PWD=/root
APPLICATION_ENV=prod01
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SSH_CONNECTION=...
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Comment: have you found an solution? I'm having exact same problem.

Comment: I have same problem with Ubuntu 20.04. Installing ca-certificates didn't help (with or without --reinstall)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,

then I reinstalled the ca certs and updated them (as mentioned above).

after that I solved the issue.

thanks :)

Comment: Please don't add 'thanks' as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Ask Ubuntu way of saying thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just removed the `--reinstall` command from
`apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`
and it worked.